# Switch template on same component in Vue

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, vue-component

I am migrating from angularjs to Vue.
Angularjs was nice in the sense that a single controller could be applied on different templates.
So using the same controller I could display it via a list.html template or a table.html template and easily switch between a list view or table view of the same data.

In vue I need to create a component that uses a fixed template. That component might have lots of business logic but I want the ability to easily switch between a list view or a table view.
What is the correct way to achieve this with Vue?

Thanks

### UPDATE

Just to add some detail. What I am currently doing is just including both views into a single template into the component with some logic to determine which one of the two to display.
This keeps it simpler as I dont have to duplicate all the logic or methods were I to separate these into two components. At the same time its very messy.
Here is a rough example of what I am doing:

```
<template>
<div>
<div v-if="showTable">
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Type</td><td>Actions</td></tr>
<tr v-for="item in items">
<td @click="loadObject(item.Uid)>{{item.Name}}</td>
<td @click="viewType(item.Uid)>{{item.Type}}</td>
<td><span @click="expandOptions(item.Uid)">Expand</span><span @click="analyze(item.Uid)"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div v-if="showList">
<div v-for="item in items">
  <div class="list" @click="loadObject(item.Uid)>{{item.Name}}</div>
  <div@click="viewType(item.Uid)>{{item.Type}}</div>
  <div><span @click="expandOptions(item.Uid)">Expand</span><span @click="analyze(item.Uid)"></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

That is a highly simplified version of what I need which ultimately has a lot of logic and methods. With this approach I can now just have all these methods and logic in one component. But managing the above template becomes very messy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) loaded using the `is` binding, in the form of:

```
<component :is="componentView" />
```

...where `componentView` can be in the `data` or a computed prop that returns a Vue component. This allows you to dictate which component to load in the `<component>` tag. Essentially, every Vue component has only one template, but you can always switch between different components.

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
const listComponent = Vue.component('list-component', {
  template: '#list-component-template',
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
});

const tableComponent = Vue.component('table-component', {
  template: '#table-component-template',
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    view: 'list',
    items: ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dolor', 'Sit', 'Amet']
  },
  methods: {
    switchView: function() {
      if (this.view === 'list') {
        this.view = 'table';
      } else {
        this.view = 'list';
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    componentView: function() {
      if (this.view === 'list') {
        return listComponent;
      } else {
        return tableComponent;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid .cell {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="switchView">Switch view</button>
  <component :is="componentView" :items="items" />
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="list-component-template">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="table-component-template">
  <div class="grid">
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" class="cell" >
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. A dynamic component solves the problem of how to easily switch between the components but it doesnt help me solve the main problem - not having to duplicate all the logic when the only difference is in display (but too complex to handle with css). Is there no other way to do it in Vue?

Comment: @Gotts Why are you worried about code duplication? If you’re using slots in your dynamic component then you can simply interweave content into it without duplication significant chunks.

Comment: it could be I am misunderstanding how to use slots here. But within each view there is a lot of functionality and logic that has to happen. How do I make all of that easily available to each view component without duplicating the logic in the component. I realize I can emit events from the view components and trigger methods in the parent but its going to be a lot of work (compared to the way it was working in angular) - so was hoping for some other solution

Comment: I added an update to my question to be clearer